# Which hardware component is causing graphics driver crash?

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which component causes my graphics driver to crash?](https://superuser.com/questions/290809/which-component-causes-my-graphics-driver-to-crash)

*This is an update of [Which component causes my graphics driver to crash?](https://superuser.com/questions/290809/which-component-causes-my-graphics-driver-to-crash) - I have still not found the culprit.*

Summary: Got new motherboard, RAM and CPU. During gaming/DXVA decoding of HD video, I'd get BSODs (with atixxx.sys in error messages) or (recoverable, no BSOD) graphic driver resets. So I replaced the graphics card. Issue persists. I replace the PSU. Issue persists. I RMA motherboard, but the retailer is unable to reproduce the error. I reassemble the system, paying extra attention to cable routing and airflow, replacing the case fans and adding some extra. Guess what? Issue persists. Grumble.

I monitored system temperatures before the most recent crash, and they were well within safe ranges (cpu around 50-54 degrees C, graphics card ~65 degrees C). Prior to RMAing motherboard, I ran memtest86+ overnight, with no errors. <strike>So the only culprit left is ...CPU?</strike>

Have run Prime95 (In-place large FFT stress test) for over 5 hrs, with no errors. CPU temp stable @ ~67 degrees C.

Per @Moab's suggestion in comments, I've had a peek at the crash dump file (with WinDbg).
It's a [VIDEO_TDR_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557263(v=vs.85).aspx), which "indicates that an attempt to reset the display driver and recover from a timeout failed", apparently. The responsible driver is most likely `atikmpag.sys`, according to WinDbg.

I've also run the FurMark Burn-in test. GPU temperatures were stable around 85 degrees C. This reproduced the graphics driver crash after ~30 minutes (this time, no BSOD). Event Viewer reports:

> Display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered.

The problem appears to be *somewhere* in the put-image-on-screen chain. The issue persists across two graphics cards and two PSUs. My CPU and RAM is tested stable.

So... do I re-RMA mobo, and give retailer instructions to run FurMark stress test? Hunt down beta BIOSes/motherboard drivers? Sacrifice a goat to the new moon? Re-test RAM, one DIMM at a time? Something else?

**UPDATE**

I am now getting additional symptoms: Mouse and keyboard are occasionally unresponsive after recover from S3 sleep. I have seen this at least 3 times.

Also, I have had one unexpected restart - I was not near the computer at the time, though.

Event Viewer is not giving me anything useful on these errors.

[detailed crash dump analysis](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3127998/debug.txt)

**System specifications:**

- 4x 2GB Corsair XMS3 1600mhz RAM
- Intel i5-760
- ASUS P7P55D-E LX P55 mobo, latest BIOS
- ASUS 6870 DirectCU
- Scythe Mugen rev.2 CPU cooler (currently fanless)
- Corsair HX 650W PSU
- Antec 300
- 1x 14cm fan in side door, 1x14cm fan in case top, 1x12cm fan case rear, 1x12cm fan case front
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Comment: Did you analyze the crash dump files?

Comment: @Moab see edit above :)

Comment: Try using "WinDBG". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: Are you overclocking? I would look for another video driver, if you have the latest, try an older version.

Comment: No OC. I am running my RAM at their rated (XMP) speed this time around (thus my i5-760 is @ 2.89 GHz), but had the same issue prior to doing so. And this had been going on since late march, and at least three driver revisions.

Comment: @Moab have now run Prime95 stress test (no issues) and FurMark Burn-in (graphics driver hung).

Comment: I am having an almost identical issue. Did you ever figure out the cause? I just RMAed my video card and they found no fault with it. The crashing seems to correspond to changes in the GPU clock speed. This makes me suspicious of the motherboard.